# What are the Equations for Climate modeling of alien planet?

Tags: resource-recommendations, planets, complex-systems, models, climate-science

I am studying complex dynamic system and I would like to analyze the climating formation of a possible alien planet considering climate as a complex system .
For this I do not want to use a whole complex model of earth also because I am not able to run such model on my laptop.
I would like instead to have a series of equations that can define simplified equations for cryosphere, atmosphere, litosphere, hydrosphere and biosphere, how those would interact considering them as separate complex systems but correlated in networked system?
Where can I find the differential equations that I could use?

Comment: I do suggest reading https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/books/Practical_Meteorology/ . It is a big read and might feel like a rabbit hole, but especially by chapter 10 and 11 you should have a set of simple enough equations to model planetary atmospheres